# Какие стили нужно задать, что бы получилась равнозначная сетка из блоков?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

Есть перечень услуг, которые идут ровно по горизонтали, но беспорядочно по вертикали. Как правильно оформить, чтобы вертикаль тоже была симметрична?
что-то на примере такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.ofera {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 2em 2.135em 0 0;
}

.list-of {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80%;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-of">
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>randaooooda</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>asdd</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>asddda</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>asssd</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>asdddds</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>raacfasdf</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>rand</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Таблицы уже не в моде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `flex`:

```css
.ofera {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
}

.list-of {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-of">
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>randaooooda</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>asdd</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>asddda</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>asssd</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>asdddds</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>raacfasdf</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>rand</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/80z7w27z/) на JSFiddle

Comment: Спасибо большое, действительно, не подумал

Comment: `flex` очень гибкий, и намного меньше строчек кода:)

Comment: А чем вас мой вариант не устроил?:)

Comment: Вы оба мне помогли, просто нельзя ставить 2 ответа)
А у вашего коллеги репутации намного меньше. Но раз это так важно, то думаю, он не будет против..))))

Comment: Я ему + поставил^^ что б в обиде небыл :)

Comment: все нормально, я не в обиде))

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял условие и вам нужно, чтобы 4 элемента шло в ряд, то вот решение:

```
<div class="list-of">
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>randaooooda</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>asdd</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>asddda</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>asssd</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>asdddds</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>raacfasdf</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ofera">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>rand</h2>
    </a>
    <p>sdfff<br>sdfsddd<br>sdffasd<br>asdddd</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.list-of {
  font-size: 0;
}
.list-of > * {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.list-of .ofera {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 25%;
}
```

Демо: https://jsfiddle.net/KirillSavko/8b64L69m/
Если я что-то не так понял - пишите в комментарии, помогу

Comment: Вот тебе и помог коллеге:)

Comment: не понял) это с сарказмом было сказано?))

Comment: Всмысле? нет:)  + поставил прост же))

Comment: понял, с меня тоже +)

Comment: Просто когда ответа оба верны нужно все же + ставить, ведь ответ верен:)

Comment: это да, в принципе эта задача решается несколькими способами, так что + тут обязателен)))

Comment: На самом деле способов ещё больше:) главное правильно оформить вопрос что бы потом пользователи смогли найти вопрос и решения к нему))

Comment: Спасибо вам Большое) Каждому. Голова уже не работает. Студент, 2 зачета сдал сегодня. Но на хлеб зарабатывать нужно. Еще раз спасибо

Comment: сам студент, понимаю вас) всегда пожалуйста